# Nginx rewrite urls with special characters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I just got a list of urls that needs to be rewritten into nginx

```
example.com/cms.php/inspiration?fullsize > /
example.com/shop/?category_id=27 > /garden/cushion.html
example.com/shop/?2008=1&vare_id=10553&variant_id=2232 > /garden/cushion/black.html
```

I tried with the following

Simple rewrite

```
rewrite /shop/?category_id=27 /garden/cushion.html permanent;
```

Location rewrite

```
location /shop/?category_id=27 {
    rewrite /shop/?category_id=27 /garden/cushion.html;
}
```

And with location where I commented special signs

```
location /shop/\?category_id=27 {
    rewrite /shop/\?category_id=27 /garden/cushion.html;
}
```

I add them directly into `server {...}` in the nginx configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, anything from the `?` onwards is the *query string* and is not part of the normalised URI used by the `rewrite` and `location` directives.

One way to achieve your objective is to test the `$request_uri` variable using a `map` directive.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default                                     0;
    /cms.php/inspiration?fullsize               /;
    /shop/?category_id=27                       /garden/cushion.html;
    /shop/?2008=1&vare_id=10553&variant_id=2232 /garden/cushion/black.html;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) { return 301 $redirect; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.