# Best way to 301 redirect huge number of urls with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

I have approx 2500 url's which I need to permanently redirect from old location to new location.

What is the best/efficient approach to do this with nginx?

1- writing 2500 rewrite rules to nginx config?
2- generating 2500 small scripts (php,Python etc.) at old locations which returns 301?
3- generating some kind of 2500 static files at old locations which contains 301 directives?
4- using map directive with 2500 items similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236108/nginx-rewrite-urls-with-special-characters/43236721#43236721) (thanks Richard Smith)
5-???

Third one seems most efficient but I dont know it is possible or not?

Thanks

Comment: One option might be to use a `map` directive, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236108/nginx-rewrite-urls-with-special-characters/43236721#43236721).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about performance difference between rewrite rules and maps? I wonder about maps or written rewrite rules are indexed in memory or not after nginx started and afraid of 2500 rules performance in a single file.

Comment: I would avoid 2500 regular expressions (rewrite or map). If you can use `map` with plain old text strings, the size of the map should not matter, as it should be optimised using a hash table (I would guess).