# Regular Expression to fix broken URL's in Nginx

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx

On my previous server that ran apache I had some htaccess rules that helped forward a certain pattern of URL's which were giving 404's to the fixed pattern.

Long time ago my URLS for my site were `http://domainname/articlename` and then I changed it to be `http://domainname/category/articlename`

Now the problem is the older links that google has are returning 404's and I want to intercept any URL that doesn't have a category and insert a fake category and then my wordpress installation can resolve the URL.

So I'm looking for a nginx solution to this problem which I presume will be in the config file somewhere that will take this URL

`http://www.criticalhit.net/prey/` (which gives a 404)

and change it to

```
http://www.criticalhit.net/fixed/prey/
```

which then resolves properly.

Comment: Is it a list of article names or is there a pattern? You could use a map for an arbitrary list. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236108/nginx-rewrite-urls-with-special-characters/43236721#43236721) for guidance.

Comment: There are over 4000 articles so it's quite the list. The pattern I want to catch is any URL that is missing the category section and isn't in a specific list that I provide. So I can exclude certain URL's from getting the middle part of the URL being added

Comment: You can use a map of excluded URLs and an `if` block to return the rewritten link, or construct `locations` for the excluded patterns and activate the rewrite from the `location /` block.

Comment: I'm comfortable with excluding my urls... however what would the rewrite and location block look like? I'm very new to nginx and can't see how to pick up URL's which are missing the middle section

Answer (score 0):

Use a named location to perform the rewrite, although this simple rewrite can be accomplished efficiently using a `return 301`.

Place a regular expression location (after the PHP location block) to bypass excluded URLs. This does not need to include the static files which are served by the `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    return 301 /category$request_uri;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
location ~ ^/(category|tags|feeds) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.