# Parse 404 url and redirect with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to remove an seo plugin from my forum, and I have MANY 404 pages to deal with.

The old url struture is :

http://example.com/board/technical-advice/something-interesting-t2824-15.html

...and the new one is:

http://example.com/board/viewtopic.php?t=2824

So I would like to parse all 404 urls coming into the /board folder, and redirect them to the new structure.

Is it possible to do this in my Nginx config? If so how? Or is there a better place?

Comment: I think this can somehow be done using `301 redirect` from `.htaccess`

Comment: Use your .htaccess to write URL redirect rule **permanent** to the new URL structure

Comment: I'd rather do a replacement in the database. Or - if you're using an existing CMS - look at routing there.

Comment: nginx fella's. NGINX, there's no .htaccess in there

Comment: As @UnamataSanatarai points out, there is no htaccess for nginx, and what one would do in htaccess in apache, is what I'm lookin for in nginx

Comment: You could use a `map` directive. Something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236108/nginx-rewrite-urls-with-special-characters/43236721#43236721)

Answer (score 1):

If this is just one format you need to do then you can use below

http://example.com/board/technical-advice/something-interesting-t2824-15.html
http://example.com/board/viewtopic.php?t=2824

```
rewrite "^/board/[^/]+/[a-z0-9-]t(\d+).*\.html$" /board/viewtopic.php?t=$1 redirect;
```

If there are lots of redirects then you should use the approach that @RichardSmith suggested in the comments on below article

[Nginx rewrite urls with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236108/nginx-rewrite-urls-with-special-characters/43236721#43236721)