# Nginx redirect issue which has query string and special characters

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

We have configured Nginx web server for our project.  We have a requirement to redirect the url which has query string and special characters.  Below is the URL.

localhost/searchPage.action?keyWord=line%20cards&overRideCatId=N

We tried 301 redirect using below rule but it is not working.
rewrite ^/searchPage.action(.*)keyWord(.*)line%2520cards&overRideCatId(.*)N https://localhost/line-cards/ permanent;

How to redirect special characters in Nginx 301 redirect rules?

Comment: this: https://superuser.com/a/1315467 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43236721/973254 might be helpful

Comment: Do you want to redirect the query as well?